# How to get selected rows values using check box in GridView asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am unable to get row values in Grid by checking check box. selected check box is always getting false in code behind. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

This is my aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="resumeSearchGrid" DataKeyNames="CandidateID"  CellPadding="5" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CandidateID" HeaderText="CandidateID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CandidateName" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailID" HeaderText=" Email Id" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" class="button"  runat="server" 
Text="Send to client" onclick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
```

This is my code behind :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in resumeSearchGrid.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect");

        if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
        {
            Name += resumeSearchGrid.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + ',';
            eMail += gvrow.Cells[2].Text + ',';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting chk as null or are you getting its checked as false?

Comment: do you have any update panel on your page? sometimes they are known to cause such problems

Comment: Initially i checked without update panel,after then checked with update panel. In both situation its not working. Still i am getting false.

Comment: seems weird!! try creating another grid in your page and only place a check box in it and see if you are able to get its checked values.

Comment: have you put trigger of submit button in your content panal for checkbox list?

Comment: @Kuashal I have added (!IsPostBack) in page load. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write `chkSelectlist` instead of `chkSelect` in `FindControl`

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelectlist");
```

And if condition only write

```
if (chk.Checked)
{

}
```

Comment: I tried it. But still i am getting false in That condition. I don't know why its not working. I created one sample application, there it's working fine. But in my application only its not working

Comment: @user3336505 in page load event your grid bind inside if (!IsPostBack) or Not ?

Comment: OMG..No. I didn't use (!IsPostBack). i added now. Its working.